# не работает @Indexed в spring cassandra

Tags: spring, cassandra

вот CassandraConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:cassandra.properties"})
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.repo"})
public class CassandraConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);

    @Autowired private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("cassandra.port")));

        HashSet<KeyspaceActionSpecification<?>> kspaces = new HashSet<>();
        kspaces.add(CreateKeyspaceSpecification
                .createKeyspace(env.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"))
                .ifNotExists()
                .withSimpleReplication(1)
        );

        cluster.setKeyspaceSpecifications(kspaces);

        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        BasicCassandraMappingContext mapCtx = new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
        mapCtx.setInitialEntitySet(CassandraEntityClassScanner.scan("com.example.model"));
        return mapCtx;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(env.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
        session.setConverter(converter());
        String action = env.getProperty("cassandra.schema.action").toUpperCase();
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.valueOf(action));

        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        Session session = session().getObject();
        CassandraTemplate ops = new CassandraTemplate(session);
        return ops;
    }

}
```

далее модель

```
@Data
@Table(value = "logs")
public class LogEntry {
    @PrimaryKey private Date time = new Date();
    @Indexed private String name;
    @Indexed private String server;
    @Indexed private String user;
    private int duration;
    private String params;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[" +
                "time: " + time.toString() + ", " +
                "name: " + name + ", " +
                "server: " + server + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return time.hashCode();
    }

}
```

и проблема в том что индексы автоматически не создаются.

Comment: Понимаю, что не отвечаю на исходный вопрос, но вам вообще нужны эти индексы? Вторичные индексы считаются антипаттерном, вместо них принято реализовывать таблицы с альтернативной конфигурацией partition key / clustering key. Можете дать ссылку на ту документацию, по которой это все должно работатть?

Comment: к сожалению ссылку найти не могу. но аннотации в spring-cassandra есть же. и они не работают. у меня

Comment: а с partition key совсем не удобно. для него нужно отдельный класс делать

Comment: Вторичными индексами вы только базу положите, у вас каждый запрос будет иметь право по всем нодам разойтись.

Comment: получается что если я захочу искать gо колонкам то мне нужно делать эту колонку ключем. Спасет ли ситуацию если я в коде выше @Indexed заменю на @PrimaryKey?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, кассандра позволяет искать только по partition key, вы сможете искать только по совокупности колонок. Как primary key превращается в partition key - отсюда не могу сказать, но 90% что в spring-cassandra это одно и то же.